# Chop text in column to 60 charactersblocks

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a worksheet that has thousands of rows and only one column `(A)`. The cells in column A can be null or up to and over `1000` characters. I need to run a macro that will loop through column A copying it to column `B`. If there are any cells that have any text `> 60` characters to cut it into blocks of `60` into the next columns.

I have code that breaks text into blocks of `60` but I don't know how to get it to copy anything under `60`, move to next row if null or loop through rows.

```
Sub x()
    Dim cLength As Long, cLoop As Long
    cLength = 60

    For cLoop = 1 To (Len([A2]) \ cLength) + 1
        [A2].Offset(, cLoop).Value = Mid([A2], ((cLoop - 1) * cLength) + 1, cLength)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

**Fastest way to handle it! (Uses no Loops. Processes the entire column in one go)**

This uses the inbuilt `Data | Text To Columns`. We are using `Fixed Width` to split the data. The below code will handle strings up to `1320` characters in length.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array( _
                        Array(0, 1), Array(60, 1), Array(120, 1), Array(180, 1), _
                        Array(240, 1), Array(300, 1), Array(360, 1), Array(420, 1), _
                        Array(480, 1), Array(540, 1), Array(600, 1), Array(660, 1), _
                        Array(720, 1), Array(780, 1), Array(840, 1), Array(900, 1), _
                        Array(960, 1), Array(1020, 1), Array(1080, 1), Array(1140, 1), _
                        Array(1200, 1), Array(1260, 1), Array(1320, 1) _
                         ), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

[image]

If you were to do it manually then you would be doing this.

[image]

Comment: To create that jagged arrays, you might want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586988/jagged-arrays-in-data-text-to-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should do your job:

```
    Sub pCopyTextToNextColumn()

        Dim wksSheet1           As Worksheet
        Dim rngColAData         As Range
        Dim rngCell             As Range
        Dim lngLastRow          As Long
        Dim cLoop As Long

        'Set the length
        cLength = 60

        'Assign worksheet
        Set wksSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'find last Row in column A
        lngLastRow = wksSheet1.Cells(wksSheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'Set Data range
        With wksSheet1
            Set rngColAData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, 1))
        End With

        'Loop through each cell in column A, and
        For Each rngCell In rngColAData.Cells
            'Length of the string is greater than 60 then loop through
            If Len(Trim(rngCell)) > cLength Then

                For cLoop = 1 To (Len(rngCell) \ cLength) + 1
                    rngCell.Offset(, cLoop).Value = Mid(rngCell, ((cLoop - 1) * cLength) + 1, cLength)
                Next

            Else
            'Else just paste the data in column B
                rngCell.Offset(, 1) = rngCell.Value

            End If

        Next rngCell

        'Release Memory
        Set wksSheet1 = Nothing
        Set rngColAData = Nothing
        Set rngCell = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code to make it generic for all rows:

```
Sub x()
    Dim cLength As Long
    Dim cLoop As Long
    Dim i As Long

    cLength = 60
    i = 1

    While i < 1001
        For cLoop = 1 To (Len(Cells(i, 1)) \ cLength) + 1
            Cells(i, cLoop + 1).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1), ((cLoop - 1) * cLength) + 1, cLength)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```