# Jagged Arrays in Data | Text To Columns

Tags: vba, excel, jagged-arrays

**What I have**

Let's take an example of this code which works.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array( _
                        Array(0, 1), Array(60, 1), Array(120, 1), Array(180, 1), _
                        Array(240, 1), Array(300, 1), Array(360, 1), Array(420, 1) _
                         ), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

**What I want**

In a small set of data, the above code works. But what if I want to go up to say `Array(2700,1)`? This means I will have to write it `46` times `Array(0, 1), Array(60, 1)...Array(1080, 1)....Array(2700, 1)`

**What I have tried**

I tried using this approach

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyArray
    Dim MyStr As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 2700 Step 60
        MyStr = MyStr & "#" & "Array(" & i & ",1)"
    Next i

    MyStr = Mid(MyStr, 2)

    MyArray = Split(MyStr, "#")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=MyArray, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Obviously that won't work as `Array(i,1)` is stored as a string in `MyArray`.

**My Question**

Is there any way we can create such kind of jagged arrays in a loop so that all I have to do is say `FieldInfo:=MyArray`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign an array to an array item like so:

```
Dim n As Long
n = 0
ReDim MyArray(2700 \ 60)
For i = 0 To 2700 Step 60
    MyArray(n) = Array(i, 1)
    n = n + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Super! Why didn't I think of that :D

Comment: ++ for being the first one to answer

Answer (score 2):

You are going correct. Instead of adding to string in loop, just create actual array items.

So this is what you will have:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyArray(20) As Variant      '<-- specify the number of items you want
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
         MyArray(i) = Array(i * 60, 1)
    Next

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=MyArray, _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Thanks this works too. Though it is a slight variation of what Rory has mentioned in his answer