# Regular Expression in ms excel

Tags: regex, excel

How can I use regular expression in excel ?

[image]

In above image I have column **A** and **B**. I have some values in column **A**. Here I need to move data after **=** in column **B**. For e.g. here in 1st row I have SELECT=Hello World. Here I want to remove **=** sign and move **Hello world** in column **B**. How can I do such thing?

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow has many posts about adding regular expressions to Excel using VBA.  For your particular example, you would need VBA to actually *move* a substring from one cell to another.

If you simply want to *copy* the substring, you can do so easily using the `MID` function:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,999),A1)
```

[image]

I used 999 to ensure that enough characters were grabbed.

`IFERROR` returns the cell as-is if an equals sign is not found.

To return the portion of string *before* the equals sign, do this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("=",A1&"=")-1)
```

In this case, I appended the equals sign to A1, so `FIND` won't return an error if not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Text to Column functionality of MS-Excel giving '=' as delimiter.

Refer to this link:
[Chop text in column to 60 charactersblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583507/chop-text-in-column-to-60-charactersblocks/26585593#26585593][1])

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Text to Column feature of excel for this:

```
Follow the below steps : 
1) Select Column A.
2) Goto Data Tab in Menu Bar.
3) Click Text to Column icon.
4) Choose Delimited option and do Next and then check the Other options in delimiter and enter '=' in the entry box.
5) Just click finish.
```

Here are URL for Text to Column : **http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html**